# Quote about miscellany (?)

Tags: quotes

I'm trying to remember a certain quote representing the concept of miscellany (or randomness perhaps). I can't give much information except that it is of the form "Of ... and ... and ... etc.", contains various 'unusual' words, and has a rhyming scheme. I could swear it is attributed to Lewis Carroll, but I could well be wrong on that.

Regretfully that's all the information I can give for now; Google is not being terribly helpful with this! If anyone has an idea, please by all means post it.

Comment: Even one of the "unusual" words might trigger a memory in one of the regulars here ...

Comment: @Robusto: Indeed... unfortunately my memory is failing me utterly right now! I'll be sure to post if one occurs to me.

Comment: I know the feeling and you have my sympathy. I wish I had more to offer.

Comment: Thanks, Cerberus... I encounter this "fingertips" feeling too often, hah.

Comment: @Noldorin: Yeah, I hate the feeling too. What happens to me is, my brain tries to give me a different word that is stored somewhere near the one I'm looking for. Like I was trying to think of the word *prosaic* the other day and my brain wanted to give me *rustic*. Stupid brain.

Comment: @Robusto: Hehe, yes, I've been there. Something to do with language being associated with the verbal/sound part of the brain I suppose! Good stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you mean the following quote from Carroll's "The Walrus and the Carpenter":

> "The time has come," the Walrus said,
>   "To talk of many things:
>   Of shoes--and ships--and sealing-wax--
>   Of cabbages--and kings--
>   And why the sea is boiling hot--
>   And whether pigs have wings."

For the full text:http://www.jabberwocky.com/carroll/walrus.html

Comment: Ah yes, you got it! Thanks very much. It seems I was right about it being from a work of Carroll, but I couldn't for the life of me find it.

Comment: (And I suppose I chose to interpret it as "miscellany", though the meaning is probably open.)